# Solution Finding : Retrieve new update from server and update using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I tried to develop a website which allows user to post status and comment each of the status.
So, each of the status will have a comment group which belongs to the status.

I apply jquery ajax with setinterval which will loop the jquery to retrieve the latest status and display it in my website.

However, when comes to comment. I tried to apply this to each of the comment group but the problem I met is when new status and comment group show in my website. Some of the javascript not triggered.

If my website have 100 status with their own comment groups which mean the website will have 100 setinterval function running. will it be a problem for performance? Is that any better ways to achieve this?

My code is in JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4mm4buzk/

```
<div id="Status">
<!-- Call this function for specific status because div no onload event -->
<script>
    TriggerGetComment(1)
</script>
<!-- This will be adding in dynamically through ajax-->
<div id="ContainerForEachOfTheStatus">
    <div style="display:none">1</div>Status/Message will be here.
    <div id="Comment1">
        <!-- Container for each of the comment -->
        <div>
            <div style="display:none">1</div>Comment Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, the question that I want to ask is
 - Is that any other way beside using setInterval to keep request to web server to check the new status or comments ?
 - What is common ways that people used to solve such problem?

Sorry for my poor english. Thank you.

Comment: no prob, but more important than english on SO is code. Do you have any to show? can you put the js and html at least into jsfiddle or codepen. You must be specific; your question lacks context...

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way, don't set a `setInterval` for every single one of those posts. You should look at [socket.io](http://socket.io) for what you're trying to do. You're going to exhaust your server with your method.

Comment: HI @Todd,

Sorry about that and thank you for telling that my question not specific enough.

Here is the code in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/4mm4buzk/

Comment: Hi @Darren,
Thank you for telling. I will look into it right now.

Comment: make a "fetch all comments" tool, and just run it every 5 seconds. it can grab new stuff only. then update each section if/as needed using the client's CPU instead of the servers. that way you drastically reduce the amount of work the server does, and you don't have to start all over.

Comment: You should have a look on websockets to push new messages to the client when they happen

Comment: Thank you everyone. I solve it by using Ratchet PHP.